# Cordova URL ping test for IOS/Android (not just network test)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Does anyone know a simple URL (https//mysite.com/test.jpg) ping test for Cordova that will check to see if it's responding?  I already have the [Cordova Plugin Network Information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) which is great for checking if the device has a connection but I'd like to display a notification that there's a problem with the server connection.

Answer (score 0):

by jQuery ajax:

```
$.ajax({url: 'https//mysite.com/test.jpg', dataType: 'jsonp', error: function(xhr,status,error){}, success: function(res){}});
```

if there is error you can get on error callback.